# Getting array position after comparing values

Tags: java

I have this problem in java:

I have two arrays, age[] and name[] | age is INT and name is String.

Then I have this data

Name | Age

John 40

Sarah 27

James 78

Terry 14

What i need to do is get the youngest one in the list. What I have done so far is creating a code to compare the Integers:

```
 public static int smallest(int[] array)
{
    int min = array[0];

    for (int k = 1; k < array.length; k++)
    {
        if (array[k] < min)
        {
            min = array[k];
        }
    }


    return min;
}
```

So my method|function returns is 14, which is correct. However, I need to get the name, in this case Terry. I have the value of the array Age but I cannot think on a way to get the number of the position of the name[] array.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Get the `index` of the element mapped to the minimum, then use that index to dereference the other array. Also, in your loop you should start looping at `0` since Arrays in Java are indexed from 0 to their length.

Comment: @Pepe Nieto you could use a hash map to store both name and age.. and then find out the youngest person

Comment: I started with 1, because I started to compare with the 0 array.

So if I would have started with 0 I will be comparing 0 with 0.

Comment: have a class level variable for the value k save it after you get the data use that integer to get the name from the second array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of the min age, keep track of the index of the min age. Then you can use that index to find the name and age and anything else (if you end up with more data in the future.

This will change your comparison slightly. Instead of:

```
if (array[k] < min)
```

You will want to do:

```
if (array[k] < array[min])
```

And instead of:

```
min = array[k];
```

You'll want to do:

```
min = k;
```

You'll also want to start with `int min = 0`.

Then at the end of the function min will represent the index of the youngest person and you can use the index to find the name and age.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int smallest(int[] array)
{
    int min = array[0];
    int minimumIndex = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k < array.length; k++)
    {
        if (array[k] < min)
        {
            min = array[k];
            minimumIndex = k;
        }
    }

    return minimumIndex;
}
```

This code will return the Minimum Index with this you get the name and age.

**NOTE**:

This is just an workaround for your problem but actual solution involves representing your fields with proper class.